# How to make a graph based on connection

Tags: python, dataframe, graph

I have a csv like below

| User | Group |
| --- | --- |
| First | A,B,C |
| Second | B |
| Third | C,D |

I want to create a graph, with node as each user, edge is drawn between users if they are in the same group. So in this case, I am expecting to get something like this [image]. Could someone please guide me on how to do it in Python?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - LOOP G over groups
   - LOOP U1 over users
        - LOOP U2 over users
              IF U1 == U2 continue
              IF U1 in G AND D U2 in G
                  Add edge U1-U2 to your favourite graph theory library ( e.g. networkx )
 - Use library to draw graph
```